# The date of audio file is same for all audio file

Tags: java, android

When I run this code I get all the list of [image give below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Gzl.jpg) audio files but, the date of all the audio files are same like 20 Jan 1970 .  below the code of AudioActivity.java. I don't know how I can do it if is possible .

```
public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

private SlideAdapter slideAdapter;

public static final int PERMIT = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.aa_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Call Tank");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    fetchSongs();
}


private void fetchSongs() {

    //define list to carry songs
    List<ModelClass> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri songLibraryUri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        songLibraryUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    } else {
        songLibraryUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    //projection
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
    };

    //sort order
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

    //Querying
    try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(songLibraryUri, projection, null, null, sortOrder)) {

        // cache the cursor indices
        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED);
        int pathColimn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


        //getting the values
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            // get values of colums for a give audio files
            long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
            long date = cursor.getLong(dateColumn);
            String path = cursor.getString(pathColimn);

            //song uri
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

            //remove .mp3 extension on song's name
            name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));

            // song item
            ModelClass song = new ModelClass(path, name, uri, date);
            // add song to songs list
            songs.add(song);

        }

        Intent i = new Intent(AudioActivity.this,Onboarding.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("songs", (Serializable) songs);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);

        //Intent intent = new Intent(AudioActivity.this,Onboarding.class);
      //  intent.putExtra("songs", (Serializable) songs);
        //show songs on rv
        showSongs(songs);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Number of Songs:" + songs.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void showSongs(List<ModelClass> songs) {
    // songs.clear();
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new Adapter(songs);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Below the code of Adapter.java

```
     public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

List<ModelClass> songs;
public Adapter(List<ModelClass> songs) {
    this.songs = songs;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

  //  View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ModelClass modelClass = songs.get(position);

        String file = modelClass.getFilename();
        holder.fileName.setText(file);

        Long dateTime = modelClass.getDate();
        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(dateTime);
        holder.date.setText(currentDate);

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        String audioPath = modelClass.getPath();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mP) {
                            mP.start();
                            holder.play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            holder.pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

                    mediaPlayer.prepare();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                holder.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return songs.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView play , pause;
    TextView fileName, date;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        play = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play);
        pause= itemView.findViewById(R.id.pause);
        fileName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fileName);
        pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        } 
      }
   } // the code end
```

**Date of all the audio files are same in the list**

This is ModalClass.java

```
public class ModelClass  {

String path,filename;
Uri uri;
Long date;

public ModelClass(String path, String filename,   Uri uri, Long date) {
    this.path = path;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.date = date;
    this.uri = uri;
}

public ModelClass() {
}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public Uri getUri() {
    return uri;
}

public void setUri(Uri uri) {
    this.uri = uri;
}

public Long getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Long date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

Comment: public class ModelClass  {

    String path,filename;
    Uri uri;
    Long date;

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show all the relevant code - and I suspect the vast majority of that code isn't actually relevant anyway. Have you debugged into the code that populates your model? What does `cursor.getLong(dateColumn)` return? That's presumably where the problem is... or at least, that would be the first thing I'd check.

Comment: I add my ModalClass activity now you can check

Comment: Again: "Have you debugged into the code that populates your model? What does `cursor.getLong(dateColumn)` return?"

Comment: I can't find it

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I can't find it" - can't find what? You've got code that calls `cursor.getLong(dateColumn)` - it's in the code that you've posted. Step into the code with a debugger to see what that's returning - or just log the value if you absolutely have to

Comment: This 1628164374  value get after cursor.getLong(dateColumn)

Comment: Right. That's a time in *seconds* since the Unix epoch (to get August 5th 2021), not *milliseconds*. It surprises me that you're getting a value in seconds, but you can just multiply it by 1000 to get the value you actually want.

Answer (score -1):

> > Long dateTime = modelClass.getDate()

You did not post the code for getDate() while there starts your problem.

It problably returns 0 for all files.

And 0 equals 20 Jan 1970.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Well getDate() just returns the value of variable date. You should go to the code where you determined the value. What you put in you will get out. And... Why didnt you confirm that the value is 0?

Comment: can you provide me ,  the code ?

Comment: If you cant answer comments then i cant provide.

Comment: which comment i have not answer?

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding , I apologize

Comment: "And 0 equals 20 Jan 1970." It really shouldn't. It should be January 1st 1970. I agree that we need to know the value returned, but I doubt that it's 0.

Comment: And as expected the value isn't 0, it's a value in *seconds* since the Unix epoch, rather than milliseconds. (Contrary to the documentation, for unexplained reasons...)